# how to access exceptions thrown by Nestjs from frontend?

Tags: error-handling, next.js, axios, nestjs

I am building backend API with Nestjs and I want to access exeptions from frontend

this is a simple example from login endpoint when user enters non-existent email :

```
const user = await this.userModel.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      throw new NotFoundException('email does not exist  .');
     }
```

now when I send request from my Nextjs application like this :

```
 await axios
        .post(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/user/login`, {
          email: values.email,
          password: values.password,
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Login catched an error : ", error);          
        });
```

I get the `NotFoundException`  as `error`:

[image]

now I want to get the `status` of this `error` (404 in this case),is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an `AxiosError`, so you should be able to access `error.response.status` [as shown in Axios's documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors)